# Access methods/properties of generic type only if the type contains those methods

Tags: c#, generics

I am relatively new to scripting, and I was wondering if I could find a way to do what I am looking to accomplish:

I am trying to write an extension method to help determine if two lists contain the same values. I found a good example for this already, but I'm having some trouble applying it to nested lists.

For example, if L1 contains l1 and l2, and L2 contains l3 and l4, and l1 and l3 both contain 1f and 1.5f and l2 and l4 both contain 2f and 2.5f, the Method would only determine that l1 != l3 and l2 != l4.

I attempted to try to call the function recursively, but even if I check to determine that the Type of the elements from the outermost list is also an IEnumerable, I still get an error that T does not contain a definition for the method. I think I understand why that is, but I'm not sure how to get around that.

My current code, for reference:

```
public static bool EqualContents<T>(this IEnumerable<T> l1, IEnumerable<T> l2)
{
    if(l1.Count() != l2.Count())
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        foreach(T t1 in l1) 
        {
            if(!l2.Any((t2) => {return t2.EqualContents(t1);}))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return !l1.Except (l2).Any ();
}
```

Comment: I think you need a better specification. The cause of your compile-time error is clear; you would need to cast `t1` and `t2` to `IEnumerable<T>` for some `T` before calling your method recursively. It is possible to construct an appropriate method invocation using reflection or `Expression`. But the implementation you show above seems flawed to me; for example, it will treat as equal a sequence `l1` where `l1` is a subset of `l2`, even if `l2` has additional elements not in `l1`. You have a similar issue with the recursive part.

Comment: I would also be concerned by the performance characteristics of this approach. Even one level of nesting of collections will incur a big algorithmic complexity hit, and it gets worse each level of nesting you do. Presumably there's some broader problem you're trying to address; maybe it would be better to step back and consider alternative solutions to that problem (seeking help with that problem here on Stack Overflow, if necessary).

Comment: As for the question as posted, it's difficult to understand your specific scenario(s) without a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're trying to do and provides a good set of sample data to test with. At the very least, please improve the question so that it's less ambiguous. With that, it may still be too broad since the code you have doesn't really even work for non-recursive sequences, requiring an extensive discussion to reach a correct solution. But it'd be a step in the right direction, anyway.

Comment: I don't think it should treat l1 as equal to l2 if l1 is a subset of l2, since the first check will return false if l1.Count() != l2.Count(), but your other comments seem valid. My specific scenario is that I'm trying to construct a system for determining probability values. Essentially a List<Event> containing events X, Y and Z would be passed to a Method to determine P(X||Y||Z), a List<List<Event>> containing {X,Y}, {A,B} and {N,M} would be passed to that Method to determine P((X||Y)&&(A||B)&&(N||M)), with further nesting continuing the And/Or pattern.

Comment: The example I posted was the case in my code that had the least moving parts, so I used it as the example, but the same issue occurs elsewhere, so I was hoping to get an answer in the general case.

Comment: _"the first check will return false if l1.Count() != l2.Count()"_ -- I see, yes. I overlooked that.